# Evaluating Maclaurin Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I would like to know how they got the highlighted part in the image below; What I have done so far is, finding the Maclaurin series for $e^x$ then substitute $2x$ for $x$ and find the Maclaurin series for $ln(1+x)$ and substitute $x^3$ for $x$, and same thing with $cos(3x)$ and then cancel ones with opposite signs. But I don't understand the highlighted part.[image]

Comment: It's FOIL on the previous line's numerator, but seems like there should be an $x^3$ term up there.

Comment: But how can it be so? I don't know if it's the same infinity, or the infinity doesn't matter?

Comment: @Eli: agreed. But the problem is the leading "1" in the first big parens on the second line---that should not be there, because it's $e^{2x} - 1$, i.e., the one gets subtracted off. Typo on the author's part, I suppose. Dick: ignoring that, the author's just taken all products of terms, one  from each series, and gathered them into like powers of $x$.

Comment: In the series for $e^{2x}-1$, note the not very visible $-1$ at the end. So the leading term is $2x$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Looks like me and John both missed that, hahaha.

Comment: After reading through comments and the post, I realized they broke out a $x^3$ from the second bracket on the second line, and everything in that bracket goes to zero except the first term which is one, and so you take the $x^3$ and multiply it into the first bracket on the second line and get the highlighted part. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the result of multiplying out the numerator in the second line. There we can get rid of $1 - 1 = 0$, so we get:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\left(2x + \frac{(2x)^2}{2!} + \frac{(2x)^2}{3!} + \dots\right)\left(x^3 - \frac{x^6}{2} + \dots\right) &= 2x^4 + 2x^5 + \dots\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Inside those dots on the right side hide infinitely more terms, which we don't know anything about *except* that they have degree $> 5$. Fortunately, we don't have to care, since the $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}$ is going to get rid of them for us (by substituting in zero for $x$).

$2x^4$ is the only term from the top that survives, since dividing by $x^4$ is enough to rid it of $x$.

So it's not the same infinity, by which I assume you mean the same quantity that the prevous $\dots$ represent. But it doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, they multiplied out a $x^3$ from the second the second bracket and that bracket goes to 1 since the first term is 1 and the rest have x which goes to zero leaving us with 1 and $x^3$ which we multiply into the first bracket. Thank you very much!